# Bash: getting keyboard input with timeout

Tags: bash

I have a script that aims to find out which key is pressed. The problem is that I don't manage it quickly because I need the timeout in the fifth digit that makes it not react quickly, or not react at all.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo echo Start
while true
do
    file_content=$(sudo timeout 0.5s cat /dev/input/event12 | hexdump)
    content_split=$(echo $file_content | tr " " "\n")
    word_counter=0
    for option in $content_split
    do
        word_counter=$((word_counter+1))
        if [ $word_counter -eq 25 ]
        then
            case $option in
                "0039")echo "<space>";;
                "001c")echo "<return>";;
                "001e")echo "a";;
                "0030")echo "b";;
                "002e")echo "c";;
                "0020")echo "d";;
                "0012")echo "e";;
                "0021")echo "f";;
                "0022")echo "g";;
                "0023")echo "h";;
                "0017")echo "i";;
                "0024")echo "j";;
                "0025")echo "k";;
                "0026")echo "l";;
                "0032")echo "m";;
                "0031")echo "n";;
                "0018")echo "o";;
                "0019")echo "p";;
                "0010")echo "q";;
                "0013")echo "r";;
                "001f")echo "s";;
                "0014")echo "t";;
                "0016")echo "u";;
                "002f")echo "v";;
                "0011")echo "w";;
                "002d")echo "x";;
                "002c")echo "y";;
                "0015")echo "z";;
            esac
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: Please write in English, not German.

Comment: I think using `timeout` in the first place is the root of both of your problems.  There may be a way you can use something like `tail` or `read` to read the events "live".

Comment: running `timeout` in the first place is wrong. You want to do work with a _stream_, so parse input in a _steaming fashion_ - in pseudocode `cat /dev/input/event12 | while read_one_byte; do parse_one_byte; done`. Do not run it periodically - that's conceptually invalid..

Answer (score 3):

Do not run `cat` in a timeout in a loop - that's just an invalid way to look at the problem. No matter how "fast" your program runs it will **always** miss some events that way. Overall [polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)) approach is just invalid here.

The parsing and linux philosophy is build around *streams* that transfers bytes. The always available *streams* are stdin, stdout and stderr. They allow to pass data from one context to another. The shell most common `|` operator allows to bind together output from one program to input of another program - and this is the way™ you should work in shell. Shell primary use is to "connect" programs together.

So you could do:

```
# read from the input
sudo cat /dev/input/mouse1 |
# transform input to hex data one byte at at time so 
# we could parse it in **shell**
xxd -c1 -p |
# read one byte and parse it in **shell**
while IFS= read -r line; do
    : parse line
done
```

but **shell is very slow** and `while read` is very slow. If you want speed (and events from input are going to be fast) do **not** use shell and use a good programming language - python, perl, ruby, at least awk - these are common scripting languages. The `case $option in` construct looks like a mapping from hex values to output strings. I could see:

```
# save one `cat` process by just calling xxd
sudo xxd -c1 -p dev/input/mouse1 |
awk 'BEGIN{
         map["1c"]="<return>";
         map["1e"]="a";
        # etc. add all other cases to mapping
     }
     { if ($0 in a) print map[$0] }
'
```

Comment: i used shel only because i want to learn bash normally i code in java or python